# Wet Saw Blade Replacement Guidance

Tags: tile, ceramic-tile, saw

I am borrowing a friends wet saw.  I tried a few cuts last night and it was leaving small chips in the tile so I am assuming that it needs a new blade.  This is my first rodeo with wet saws.  In researching this I noticed there are a few styles of blades on the market, what are the pros/cons of each of the following types: continuous, turbo, and segmented?  I am cutting 12 ceramic glazed tile if that matters.

Comment: Let's address your assumption first. Is the diamond-impregnated rim of the blade gone, or mostly gone? If not, maybe you have some other problem. How large of "chips"? Any abrasive saw will leave the tile glaze a bit chewed up. Did you have good water flow?

Answer (score 3):

I find it helps to go very slowly if you want to reduce chipping.  Even with a brand new blade there will be some small chips when cutting the ceramic tiles, but when you lay them the cut edge will not be exposed because you'll lay your cuts against the inside edge/wall of whatever you are tiling, and your grout will hide it anyway.